# using Spring JPA how to read multiple reference data from DB views

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I would like to fetch read only data from multiple DB views,   using Spring JPA
That data is just reference data  Data like colors, printer types, countries, etc
The reference data is always aligned [key, value]
I have multiple DB views for example:

```
v_color:   R,RED, # B,BLUE    # G, GREEN     etc
v_country: US,USA # FR,France # TB, Free Tibet   etc
v_printer: EP, Epson # HP, HP # KY, Kyocera
```

I would like to have the same ReferenceData @Entity class for them

```
@Entity
@Table(name="V_REF_DATA" , schema="APP")
public class ReferenceData {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id; //The rownum!

    @Column(name="LABEL")
    String label;

    @Column(name="VALUE")
    String value;
```

with a single repository like so:

```
public interface ReferenceDataRepository extends JpaRepository<ReferenceData ,String> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT ID,LABEL,VALUE  FROM v_color nativeQuery = true)
    List<ReferenceData> getColorValues();

    @Query(value = "SELECT ID,LABEL,VALUE  FROM v_country", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ReferenceData> getCountryCodesValues();

    // same for all others
}
```

Is it possible/recommended?

Answer (score -2):

You can try something like this

```
TypedQuery< ReferenceData> query =
em.createNamedQuery(SELECT ID,LABEL,VALUE  FROM v_color);
List<ReferenceData> results = query.getResultList();
```